# I need an explanation on slice()

Tags: javascript, function, slice, palindrome

I was completing javascript exercises and got stuck on creating a function which checks if a string is a palindrome. For your reference, [this](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-solution.php?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2FaleDItU%2F2%2Fedit%3Fhtml%2Cjs%2Coutput&r=Write%20a%20JavaScript%20function%20that%20checks%20whether%20a%20passed%20string%20is%20palindrome%20or%20not?) was the given solution.

I understand what slice() does as a method, and I followed the function here until the point where it checks to see if the first letter matches the last.

> if (cstr[x] != cstr.slice(-1-x)[0])

What is going on with the parameter values of the slice method? I was expecting the parameters to slice the last letter and I presume it does but I would appreciate some help in pointing out how!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp - see the example with negative parameter

Comment: When you want to know how something in JavaScript works, look it up on MDN. Here is [the entry for `slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Comment: @Mathletics Thanks for the link, I'll be sure to reference it from now on.

Comment: You're not asking about `slice()`. you're asking about `slice(-1-x)[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's pop open the console and take a look!

```
> var s = 'abcde'
"abcde"
> s[0]
"a"
> s.slice(-1)
"e"
> s.slice(-1)[0]
"e"
> s[1]
"b"
> s.slice(-1 - 1)
"de"
> s.slice(-1 - 1)[0]
"d"
```

As I hope you can see by now, slicing with a negative number `-n` will return the last `n` characters of the string, with `n = 1` being the last character. So to have the palindrome test work correctly, you need to slice at `-1 - x` (the "x-th from last" character).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes plenty of sense.

Answer (score 0):

> `arr.slice([begin[, end]])`

#### Parameters

**begin**

Zero-based index at which to begin extraction. As a negative index, begin indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(-2) extracts the last two elements in the sequence. If begin is omitted, slice begins from index 0.

**end**

Zero-based index at which to end extraction. slice extracts up to but not including end. slice(1,4) extracts the second element up to the fourth element (elements indexed 1, 2, and 3). As a negative index, end indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(2,-1) extracts the third element through the second-to-last element in the sequence. If end is omitted, slice extracts to the end of the sequence (arr.length).

#### Description

slice returns a shallow copy of elements from the original array. Elements of the original array are copied into the returned array as follows:

For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.

For strings and numbers (not String and Number objects), slice copies strings and numbers into the new array. Changes to the string or number in one array does not affect the other array.

If a new element is added to either array, the other array is not affected.